# grails development: eclipse vs. intellij idea

Tags: javascript, spring, grails, suite

I downloaded sts and installed the grails/groovy plugins which is fine, but I can not use the JavaScript functionality like jumping through classes and functions in the JavaScript editor.

When I click `command` and on the functions name, I get a dialog saying "you have to make this a JavaScript project etc." :( :(

`intellij` is much better at this I think, but it takes all my cpu usage which is really sad :( so I need to switch to eclipse...

My question is: Why can't I use the JavaScript editor plugin from eclipse when my  project is a "grails project"?

Comment: 100% CPU utilization by IntelliJ IDEA is definitely not normal (except during indexing on the first startup). If you post details about your problem (with steps to reproduce) on the Jetbrains forums, you would certainly get help.

Comment: i will give that a try but i already tried this:
http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2008/02/10-tips-to-increase-intellij-idea.html

Comment: These are generic tips for improving performance, while what you are experiencing is most likely a bug.

Comment: i just tested the IdeaX-IU-98.311.app and it is much much better in case of cpu usage :) problem solved, i don't need that "unstable" eclipse plugin for grails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse's JavaScript editor is part of the Eclipse Web Tools Project (WTP). Thus, it's shipped with SpringSource Tools Suite (STS).

In new STS Grails projects as created by the Grails project creation wizard, however, the *JavaScript project facet* is not enabled by default.

To enable it,

- right-click on the project root in the Project View,
- select *Properties*,
- in the *Properties dialog*, select *Project Facets*,
- click *Convert to faceted form...*,
- mark the *JavaScript* checkbox,
- and click *OK*.

After that,

- there will be a new top-level item *JavaScript Resources* (where you can browse the sources of ECMA and third-party JavaScript files),
- and there'll be *code inspection* and *completion* in HTML `<script>` tags
- and JavaScript *source files* (file extension: *.js*),
- including for third-party libraries.

Comment: @robbbert has the eclipse JS editor still lack things like refactoring, code coloring, good js error detection, etc?

Comment: @hvgotcodes, I'm not regularly working with it; so I cannot really tell. - Basic refactoring affects HTML files that reference refactored JavaScript files but does not affect Grails GSP files. Code coloring exists. Error detection will be quite limited due to JavaScripts dynamic nature. - Additionally, there are ApiDoc tooltips, and also basic navigation ("go to source", etc.) between JavaScript source files. - The plugin apparently has made some progress over the last years.

Comment: @robbbert i ask because ive been using intellij (paying for it) for its js support, which is MUCH better than eclipses.  Or at least it was last year...

Comment: @hvgotcodes, I just had a brief look at IDEA's (community edition) JavaScript capabilities, evaluating all features mentioned above. - Undoubtedly, Eclipse's JavaScript support excels IDEA's by a magnitude, at least. - Nevertheless, now let's focus on the original question again. Thanks

Comment: the question was answered right but i stick to idea for the reasons robert just talked about :) i need to accept the high cpu usage of idea :(

Comment: new i get: Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'JavaScript Validator' on project 'myProj'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.sourceStart(SourceTypeBinding.java:1242)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.incompatibleReturnType(ProblemReporter.java:1705)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodVerifier.reportIncompatibleReturnTypeError(MethodVerifier.java:510)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodVerifier.checkAgainstInheritedMethods(MethodVerifier.java:138)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodVerifier.checkMethods(MethodVerifier.java:...

Comment: sorry, this comes from the ECLIPSE Facet

Comment: @hvgotcodes IDEA's (community edition) does NOT come with web and JS support. You need to have the ultimate edition or WebStorm to actually test it's JS support.